# In a Hilbert Space: Minimal $\Leftrightarrow$ Biorthogonal

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Perhaps obvious, but I'm struggling a bit with (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) only.

> **Proposition.** Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> i) Let $S_n := \overline{\text{span}\{x_n : n \neq m\}}$. For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_m \notin S_n$.
>
> ii) Exists $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $H$ that is biorthogonal to $x_m$, i.e. the inner product is $1$ when $n = m$ and $0$ otherwise.

---

**My idea:** I suppose if we let $S_n^{\perp}$ be the orthogonal complement of $S_n$, then for any $y_n \in S_n^{\perp}$, we have $\langle x_m, y_n \rangle = 0$. But when $n = m$, how can I be sure that $\langle x_m, y_n \rangle = 1$?

Comment: which reference is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) implies ii): There exists a continuous linear functional which has the value $1$ at $x_n$ and the value $0$ on $span \{x_i: i \neq n\}$. Continuous linear functionals are given by inner product with some element so we get $y_n$ such that $\langle  y_n, x_m \rangle=0$ for $ m \neq n$ and $1$ for $m=n$.

ii) implies i) is obvious: If $x_n $ is in the closure of the span of $\{x_i: i \neq n\}$ then the fact that $y_n$ is orthogonal to eaxh $x_i, i \neq n$ implies that $y_n$ is orthogonal to $x_n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to argue i) to ii) using only the concept of orthogonality? I know Hahn-Banach implies i) to ii) easily, but it is a little later in the book. So, I assume we don't necessarily need it with respect to Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @EzioBosso Do yo know that if $M$ is  a closed subspace of $H$ then $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$?